# IIS Dynamic IP Restrictions whitelist

Tags: iis, web-config, rate-limiting, whitelist

Please could you give me a steer on how to specify a whitelist of IP addresses when using site-wide DIPR?

```xml
<security>
  <dynamicIpSecurity denyAction="Forbidden">
    <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="5000" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="86399999"/>
  </dynamicIpSecurity>
</security>
```

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. It certainly doesn't seem to be possible from the docs and ipsecurity doesn't pipeline with DIPR. The only option I can think of is writing my own IIS module to do a similar thing to DIPR. Perhaps the code can be found somewhere and modified?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this. The UI shown in the [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions#configuring-dynamic-ip-restrictions) is out of date, though. Instead, you go to "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" (IIS 10) and add some "Allow" IPs and/or ranges.

In your *web.config* or *applicationHost.config,* a sibling element will be added that looks like this:

```xml
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
    <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true" />
</ipSecurity>
```

"Allowed" IPs are able to skip your dynamic filtering.

### Proxy mode

If you have some kind of proxy server(s) (load balancer, WAF, CDN, etc.) that sit between IIS and the website visitor, you'll need to enable Dynamic Filtering's "Proxy mode" option. Next you'll need to add all your proxy IP ranges to the "Allowed" IPs.

The filtering will skip any IPs in your "Allowed" list, starting with the actual incoming IP and then last-to-first on the IPs listed in the `X-Forwarded-For` header. The first IP encountered that is not in the "Allowed" list is the IP counted towards your for dynamic filtering rules. For more details, see [this Wade Hilmo post](https://blogs.iis.net/wadeh/dynamic-ip-restriction-proxy-mode) on IIS.net.